# Show that $-(\lambda_2\lambda_4-\lambda_2\lambda_6-\lambda_4\lambda_5)/(\lambda_1\lambda_4\lambda_5+\lambda_2\lambda_3\lambda_6)=A$

Tags: prime-numbers

Let $A,B,C$ be three pairiwise coprime positive integers, i.e., there exist six integers $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},\lambda_{3},\lambda_{4},\lambda_{5},\lambda_{6}$ such that

$$\lambda_{1}A+\lambda_{2}B=1$$

$$\lambda_{3}A+\lambda_{4}C=1$$

$$\lambda_{5}B+\lambda_{6}C=1$$

Solving with respect to $A,B,C$, we get

$$A=-(\lambda_{2}\lambda_{4}-\lambda_{2}\lambda_{6}-\lambda_{4}\lambda_{5})/(\lambda_{1}\lambda_{4}\lambda_{5}+\lambda_{2}\lambda_{3}\lambda_{6})$$

$$B= (\lambda_{1}\lambda_{4}-\lambda_{1}\lambda_{6}+\lambda_{3}\lambda_{6})/(\lambda_{1}\lambda_{4}\lambda_{5}+\lambda_{2}\lambda_{3}\lambda_{6})$$

$$C= (\lambda_{2}\lambda_{3}+\lambda_{1}\lambda_{5}-\lambda_{3}\lambda_{5})/(\lambda_{1}\lambda_{4}\lambda_{5}+\lambda_{2}\lambda_{3}\lambda_{6})$$

Generally, it is not possible to decide if $\lambda_{1}\lambda_{4}\lambda_{5}+\lambda_{2}\lambda_{3}\lambda_{6}$ is not zero and one can find examples about this.

My **question**:

If there exist some $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},\lambda_{3},\lambda_{4},\lambda_{5},\lambda_{6}$ verifying $(\lambda_{1}\lambda_{4}\lambda_{5}+\lambda_{2}\lambda_{3}\lambda_{6})$ is not zero and $(\lambda_{2}\lambda_{4}-\lambda_{2}\lambda_{6}-\lambda_{4}\lambda_{5})(\lambda_{1}\lambda_{4}\lambda_{5}+\lambda_{2}\lambda_{3}\lambda_{6})<0$, then show that the expression $-(\lambda_{2}\lambda_{4}-\lambda_{2}\lambda_{6}-\lambda_{4}\lambda_{5})/(\lambda_{1}\lambda_{4}\lambda_{5}+\lambda_{2}\lambda_{3}\lambda_{6})$ must be a representation of the positive integer $A$.

Comment: $\lambda_i=1$ contradicts your question. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Zerox: Yes. the lamds are not arbitrary, they are a result of Bézout theorem and you have infinitely of them.

Comment: from ypour earlier question, answer by @Chrystomath  Let $A=2\times11$, $B=3\times13$, $C=5\times7$. Then $$\begin{matrix}16A-9B=1\\8A-5C=1\\9B-10C=1\end{matrix}$$ yet $16.5.9=9.8.10$.

Comment: @WillJagy: All the question depends on the main assumption that the determinant is not a zero among other conditions.

Comment: good. Again, have you taken a class in linear algebra?  Your question is a standard matrix construction

Comment: @WillJagy: The question is about the fact that the positive integer can be represented by rational numbers.

Answer (score 2):

$$
M =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
   0 & \lambda_2 &  \lambda_1 \\
   \lambda_4 & 0 &  \lambda_3 \\
   \lambda_6 &  \lambda_5 &  0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
in
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
   0 & \lambda_2 &  \lambda_1 \\
   \lambda_4 & 0 &  \lambda_3 \\
   \lambda_6 &  \lambda_5 &  0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
   C\\
   B \\
   A \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
   1\\
   1 \\
   1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
M^{-1} =
\frac{1}{ \lambda_6  \lambda_3  \lambda_2 +  \lambda_5  \lambda_4  \lambda_1} \hspace{2mm}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  - \lambda_5  \lambda_3 &   \lambda_5  \lambda_1 &  \lambda_3  \lambda_2 \\
    \lambda_6  \lambda_3 & - \lambda_6  \lambda_1 &  \lambda_4  \lambda_1 \\
    \lambda_5  \lambda_4 &  \lambda_6  \lambda_2 & - \lambda_4  \lambda_2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Indeed, it is routine to confirm the matrix product
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
   0 & \lambda_2 &  \lambda_1 \\
   \lambda_4 & 0 &  \lambda_3 \\
   \lambda_6 &  \lambda_5 &  0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  - \lambda_5  \lambda_3 &   \lambda_5  \lambda_1 &  \lambda_3  \lambda_2 \\
    \lambda_6  \lambda_3 & - \lambda_6  \lambda_1 &  \lambda_4  \lambda_1 \\
    \lambda_5  \lambda_4 &  \lambda_6  \lambda_2 & - \lambda_4  \lambda_2 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
     \lambda_6  \lambda_3  \lambda_2 +  \lambda_5  \lambda_4  \lambda_1  & 0 &  0 \\
   0 &   \lambda_6  \lambda_3  \lambda_2 +  \lambda_5  \lambda_4  \lambda_1  &  0 \\
   0 &  0 &    \lambda_6  \lambda_3  \lambda_2 +  \lambda_5  \lambda_4  \lambda_1  \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

This tells us that
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
   C\\
   B \\
   A \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\frac{1}{ \lambda_6  \lambda_3  \lambda_2 +  \lambda_5  \lambda_4  \lambda_1} \hspace{2mm}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  - \lambda_5  \lambda_3 &   \lambda_5  \lambda_1 &  \lambda_3  \lambda_2 \\
    \lambda_6  \lambda_3 & - \lambda_6  \lambda_1 &  \lambda_4  \lambda_1 \\
    \lambda_5  \lambda_4 &  \lambda_6  \lambda_2 & - \lambda_4  \lambda_2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
   1\\
   1 \\
   1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc   \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc   \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc   \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc   \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  $$

hello world